# How can I use withRouter in react router v6 for passing props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Before, you would need to wrap something like this `export default withRouter(name of component)`  and now it is different in react-router v6.

I have this button where once you clicked this, it will take you to another page including the value inside my `tableMeta.rowData[0]`.
I tried using `navigate = useNavigate()`, but I do not know how to pass the value of `tableMeta.rowData[0]`

```
   {
      name: "Edit",
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
            <Button
              color="success"
               onClick={
            () => navigate("/edit-products")
            // console.log(tableMeta.rowData[0])
          }
            >
              Edit
            </Button>
          );
        },
      },
    },
```

In React-router v6, how can I do this similar to a `withRouter` before?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is deprecated. You can recreate it using the hooks version:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export function withRouter<ComponentProps>(Component: React.FunctionComponent<ComponentProps>) {
    function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: ComponentProps) {
        const location = useLocation();
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const params = useParams();

        return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
    }

    return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

For more details [check this out](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)

Comment: Just finished implementing it and it works. Thank you

Comment: If I use this `withRouter` to wrap a component, is it possible to access `history` in that component? I am having trouble trying to execute `history.push('/')` inside the component, because `history` is undefined.

Comment: You need to use `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory`. [Reference](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory)